# TeamCity - copy published artifacts to network location

Tags: java, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm using Deployer-Plugin (`SMB Deployer`) with TeamCity to copy the setup file to a network location. Unfortunately there are some problems with this SMB Deployer and I get Java out of memory exception [as described here](https://bitbucket.org/nskvortsov/deployer/issue/20/out-of-memory-exception). The workaround does not seem to work. Is there any other way to just do simple file copy of my build artifact to a network location ? It is just one setup file and I do not want any overkill solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution. using commmand line runner after the build step. And then using xcopy. This is already answered in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2828415/949702)

Becareful in specifying source and destination to xcopy. In my case, I had spaces in the path location which cause troubles. Finally the answer was to just simply enclose the paths in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the Command Line Runner to run a shell command to copy the files into the desired location